# Law of iterated expectations, Binomial Dist.

Tags: conditional-expectation, conditional-probability

- In each period, $X_i$ are drawn from i.i.d. Binomial ($N_i$,$\alpha$)
- The number of trials in period $i+1$ (i.e.$N_{i+1}$) depends on the number of successes in period $i$
- In particular, $N_{i+1}$ is equal to realized $X_i$
- Further let's assume that $N_1=1$

In this stochastic process, I would like to compute the following:

$E\big[\frac{1+X_1+X_2+...+X_t}{1+N_1+...+N_t}\big]$

I would like to know whether the following calculation is correct..

$E\big[\frac{1+X_1+X_2+...+X_t}{1+N_1+...+N_t}\big]=E\big[E\big[\frac{1+X_1+X_2+...+X_t}{1+N_1+...+N_t}|N_1,...,N_t\big]\big]$

$=E\big[\frac{1}{1+N_1+...+N_t}\big]+\alpha E\big[\frac{N_1+...+N_t}{1+N_1+...+N_t}\big]$

Comment: What does $p(X_1\mid N_1)$ mean ? What is $N_1$ ? a r.v. ? What are $N_2,...,N_t$ ?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have revised the question..

Comment: What does $p(N_1+...+N_t)$ mean? What does it mean for $N_i$ to be Binomial $(N_i,p)$? You cannot define something in terms of itself.

Comment: @Michael Thanks for your comment. I have revised the question.

Comment: I think this has been asked before. So I think you mean $X_i$ is conditionally independent of the past, given $N_i$. Then your last line is incorrect. $$ E[X_1+X_2|N_1,N_2]= N_2 +\alpha N_2$$

Comment: @Michael Great! Thank you so much. In fact, I have another question related to this specific question. I will post that as a separate question, for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer just summarizes my last comment:

1) It seems the $\{X_i\}$ are not independent and identically distributed (i.i.d.)  as described, rather each $X_i$ is conditionally independent of the past, given the value of $N_i$.

2) If $X_1=N_2$ then we get
$$ E[X_1+X_2|N_1, N_2] = E[N_2+X_2|N_1,N_2] = N_2 + \alpha N_2$$
and so 
\begin{align}
E\left[\frac{1+X_1+X_2}{1+N_1+N_2}\right] &= E\left[\frac{1}{1+N_1+N_2}\right] + E\left[\frac{E[X_1+X_2|N_1, N_2]}{1+N_1+N_2}\right] \\
&= E\left[\frac{1}{1+N_1+N_2}\right] + E\left[\frac{N_2(1+\alpha)}{1+N_1+N_2}\right]
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you! I have posted the related question here. I would appreciate any inputs- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3204029/number-of-trials-depends-on-the-number-of-successes-in-the-previous-period